# Mongodb. How to query using Regex.IsMatch for array of strings

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, iqueryable

Could you please explain how to use Regex.IsMatch on the IEnumerable property.

I tried to do it like this:

```
var portfolios = Collection.AsQueryable();
portfolios = portfolios.Where(portfolio => portfolio.KeyWords.Any(keyword => Regex.IsMatch(keyword, "hal", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));
```

where `KeyWords` is the property - `public IEnumerable<string> KeyWords { get; set; }`

as a result i see that i recieved such query:

```
{aggregate([{ "$match" : { "KeyWords" : { "$elemMatch" : { "" : /hal/i } } } }])}
```

But it seems that this query does not work because the return result is 0.

To clarify what i need. I have a document with structure like:

```
{
    "_id" : "5b488f1f666ba93004f990e0",
    "KeyWords" : [ 
        "New portfolio", 
        "Bayern", 
        "Halana", 
        "6"
    ],
}
```

What i want is to find all documents with specific query by Regex.IsMatch for objects in KeyWords array.
For example i want to find all documents with where Keywords contains object that contains text "hal"

Thanks

Comment: Well the conditions are incorrect. What are you actually trying to match in the document? Why `Any()`? Are you trying to match a "list of regular expressions" or an "expression against any of a list of strings in the document"? Showing the document you expect to match makes it much clearer.

Comment: Neil Lunn, could you please explain how to create correct condition. What i actually have is document something like
{
    "_id" : "5b488f1f666ba93004f990e0",
    "KeyWords" : [ 
        "New portfolio", 
        "Bayern", 
        "Halana", 
        "6"
    ],
}

and what i want is find all documents that have keyword with regex.match